# Nested method in Activity - WeakReferences and ReferenceQueues

Tags: java, android, memory

My goal is to reduce the memory footprint of my application.

Here is a snippet of code

```
private void showWelcome(){

        LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent);
        WeakReference<LinearLayout> llWeak = new WeakReference<>(LinearLayout);

        if (greetingContextVS.getCurrentView().equals(llWeak.get()) == true){
            greetingContextVS.showNext();
        }

}
```

I'm calling this method from onStart if needed. It displays the correct LinearLayout for the situation. My question is; how do WeakReferences work here? Do they matter? Before I just had the StrongReference to the layout and was done with it. But my understanding of WeakReferences is that they will only be held in memory if there are strong references pointing to them. Without using a WeakReference there is a ViewSwitcher preventing my layout from exiting memory. After i added the reference it should be out of memory when method terminates, correct?

Follow up question: whats the deal with ReferenceQueue? To my understanding the type you pass along is the same type of object the WeakReference holds. So if I have a Weak LinearLayout then I need a LinearLayout Queue. So if I have many different objects held in WeakReferences wouldn't that make things more complicated?

Comment: Why are you using a WeakReference here, the variable goes out of scope as soon as the method exits anyway.

Comment: Thats what I'm confused about. If you have variables in a method stack once the method terminates the variables are subject to GC, right? Are there instances where this isn't true? When should I use WeakReferences?

Comment: Yes, as soon as there are no strong references to an object it is eligible for garage collection. So if the only strong reference to an object was a local variable in method it will be eligible as soon as the method ends.

Comment: In Android, one use for weak references is to hold a reference to a listener that could be something like an Activity. The object holding the reference would be doing something outside the Activity lifecycle. So if the Activity was being destroyed it would need to be a WeakReference otherwise the Activity could be prevented from being garbage collected and you have a huge memory leak. I'm sure you can find more uses with Google.